# Pivot Column values to be Column Names using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table (simplified view) like this:

```
SellerID businessDate sales_total
A-123    1/1/2017     12.05
A-123    1/1/2017     126.75
B-223    1/1/2017     2.75
B-223    1/1/2017     31.75
C-444    1/1/2017     55.55
A-123    1/2/2017     12.05
A-123    1/2/2017     126.75
B-223    1/2/2017     10.75
C-444    1/2/2017     31.75
C-444    1/2/2017     55.55
```

And the data continues like that

What I would like to do is have the date values as the columns and the sales total for each SellerID as a single row like this:

```
SellerID  1/1/2017 1/2/2017 .....
A-123     300      100      .....
B-223     150      60       .....
C-444     120      55       .....
D-555     0        149      .....
```

My thinking is that I can easily find the daily best seller, and find the SellerID's who fall within below 3-std deviations of the mean for each selling day to find SellerID's who might not be performing well.

Thank you

Comment: Are the values count? or is that mean? If its plain pivoting read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe

Comment: There is not possible use `pivot_table` `df.pivot_table(index='SellerID', columns='businessDate', values='sales_total', aggfunc='sum')`?

Comment: @jezrael I didn't realize there was a function to pivot!

Comment: @jezrael the df.pivot_table works great, if I want to get the mean of the counts with the aggfunc do I pass a list of strings?

Comment: @codebase5000 - there is not necessary `aggfunc`, because default `aggfunc='mean'` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pandas, one can easily pivot table a dataframe, for your specific example, one can solve it as in the image bellow:

[image]

Comment: if I have another values column, can I specify that?  like TaxTotal?

Comment: Ty - I do work out a lot.

Comment: This is concise and intuitive; beautiful brain of yours